# List-item fixed width not working properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, html-lists

I am trying to create an unordered list of books. They should have fixed widths. For some reason, every time I add `overflow: hidden;` to it, the fixed width does not work.

I can see in devtools that the style is being applied to the list item, but it is not at the width I set it to. Can someone please point out the error?

```css
ul.sideul {
  display: inline-flex;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 360px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

ul.sideul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 238px;
  height: 277px;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding-top: 49px;
  --bookmark: #A68AF5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sideul">
  <li>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19.28" height="30.849" viewBox="0 0 19.28 30.849">
        <path
          class="a"
          d="M8.355,1.928V32.777l9.64-9.64,9.64,9.64V1.928Z"
          transform="translate(-8.355 -1.928)"
        />
      </svg>
    <p class="head">Notes for Work. Going Home.</p>
    <p class="body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, nam! Lorem lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
    <p class="end">8 min Read</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19.28" height="30.849" viewBox="0 0 19.28 30.849">
        <path
          class="a"
          d="M8.355,1.928V32.777l9.64-9.64,9.64,9.64V1.928Z"
          transform="translate(-8.355 -1.928)"
        />
      </svg>
    <p class="head">Notes for Work. Going Home.</p>
    <p class="body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, nam! Lorem lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
    <p class="end">8 min Read</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `width` property does have effect on your `<li>`s if you remove the `width` from your `<ul>`.

Comment: You have several conflicting overriding positional styling attributes and conflicting widths of ul v li. Remove position absolute and float and remove width from ul, as this will crop your li tags. Replace display: inline flex with just flex and choose flex-direction to be either col or row.

Comment: I actually wanted the user to be able to scroll vertically through the list items, thus I set a fixed width for the <ul> also. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: you want it to scroll horizontaly or just to have the width

Comment: Just wanted to scroll horizontally. I didn't know it was possible to scroll without fixed width!

Comment: you can use flex-shrink:0; or min-width instead of width on li tag

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, @godfather.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to add

```
ul li{    
  flex-shrink: 0; 
}
```

As Godfather kindly pointed out in the comments.